# Association size/limit validation fails in spec test

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec

My School model has a has many association with it's students as well as a one-to-one assocation with a license which has a user capacity field. I would like to impose the validation to restrict the student size to that of the license capacity so I had the following set-up in place:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base    

  has_one :license
  has_many :students

  delegate :user_capacity, :to => :license

  validate :within_user_capacity    

  def within_user_capacity
    return if students.blank?
    errors.add(:students, "too many") if students.size > user_capacity
  end    

end
```

This is the spec that I'm using to test this validation, **assume a user capacity of 100**:

```
it "should fail validation when student size exceeds school's user capacity" do
    school = FactoryGirl.create(:school_with_license)
    puts school.user_capacity # => 100
    puts school.students.size # => 0
    0...100.times {|i| school.students.build(...)}
    puts school.students.size # => 100
    #build the 101st student to trigger user capacity validation
    school.students.build(...).should_not be_valid
end
```

However, this always results in a failure - I see the message:

```
Failure/Error: school.students.build(...).should_not be_valid
       expected valid? to return false, got true
```

**edit**

Seems to be a problem with FactoryGirl, the puts statements within the spec tell me the association size is being increased, but further debugging inside the model as the validation is triggered shows that it's never increased. Even if I explicitly save the built records inside of the spec loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are asserting that the last student added is invalid (`build` returns the new student), when you want to assert that the school is invalid. Do you need to do something like this instead?:

```
school.students.build(...)
school.should_not be_valid
```

Comment: Good thinking, I think what I'm looking for is a validation error to trigger as soon as the last student is built and the `user_capacity` is exceeded. Does that mean I need to move the validations into the Student model? It doesn't exactly feel clean for School business logic to be taking place inside of the student model. In any case I tried asserting the validity of the school rather than the student as you suggested and I'm still not having any success.

Comment: Validations on Rails models are normally triggered when the `valid?` method is called (often as a side-effect of the `save` method) rather than when attributes change. It doesn't really make sense to move the validations to the student class because its business logic about the school not the individual students. I can't see why your test is still failing, to work out why I would try quickly adding `puts` statements to the `within_user_capacity` method to confirm that its being called and that the `students.size` is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make simple validation, without delegation.

I checked your approach in my application, it generally works with a fix that Steve suggested in his answer (`School` should be checked for validity).

So I would suggest the following code:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :students

  validate :within_user_capacity    

  def within_user_capacity
    errors.add(:students, "too many") if students.size > 1
  end    
end
```

Next, open console: `RAILS_ENV=test rails c`

```
> school = FactoryGirl.create :school
> school.valid?
=> true
> school.students.build
> school.students.size
=> 1
> school.valid?
=> true
> school.students.build
> school.students.size
=> 2
> school.valid?
=> false
> school.errors
=> ... @messages={:students=>["too many"]} ...
```

If this works, you can fix your Rspec code.